# How set end day based on start day in jQuery Mobile date picker?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I use jQuery-Mobile-DateBox for date and time picker in jQueryMobile.

```
<input id="start" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "afterToday": true, "useFocus": true, "overrideDateFormat": "%m/%d/%Y"}'>
<input id="end" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "afterToday": true, "useFocus": true, "overrideDateFormat": "%m/%d/%Y"}'>
```

I need not to allow user to select end day that are before start day.

```
 $("#end").datebox("minDays", $("#start").val());
```

The above code doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, please check the updated answer below.

Comment: I tend to recommend that the phrase "doesn't work" is excised from the lexicon completely - it isn't very helpful. What specifically about this code doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to disabled date as per selection of start or end dates:

If a date is selected in start datebox, then end date will be limited to selection of days after start date (inclusive of start date) and vise-verse for end date too.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){ 
    $('#end-date').bind('datebox', function(e, p) {
        if ( p.method === 'open') {

          // Make it a date
          var startDate = new Date($('#start-date').val());

          var todaysDate = new Date();    
          // Length of 1 Day
          var lengthOfDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 

          // Get the difference
          var diff = parseInt((((startDate.getTime() - todaysDate.getTime()) / lengthOfDay)+1)*-1,10); 

          // Set minDays to disallow anything earlier
          $('#end-date').datebox({'minDays': diff});
        }

    });  

     $('#start-date').bind('datebox', function(e, p) {
        if ( p.method === 'open') {

          // Make it a date
          var endDate = new Date($('#end-date').val());

          var todaysDate = new Date();    
          // Length of 1 Day
          var lengthOfDay =  1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; 

          // Get the difference            
            var diff = parseInt((((endDate.getTime() - todaysDate.getTime()) / lengthOfDay)+1),10);

          // Set minDays to disallow anything earlier
          $('#start-date').datebox({'maxDays': diff});
        }

    });  

});
```

check the updated fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/QTuma/6/

OR as per below solution a simpler method to set min and max:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){ 
    $('#start-date').bind('datebox', function(e, p) {
        if ( p.method === 'set') {
             var endDate = $('#start-date').val().replace(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/,'$3-$1-$2');
            $('#end-date').attr({'min':endDate,'max':'2999-01-01'});
            $('#end-date').datebox('applyMinMax');
        }
    }); 

     $('#end-date').bind('datebox', function(e, p) {
        if ( p.method === 'set') {
             var endDate = $('#end-date').val().replace(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/,'$3-$1-$2');
            $('#start-date').attr({'min':'1000-01-01','max':endDate});
            $('#start-date').datebox('applyMinMax');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent end day from been lower then a start day

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/QTuma/

#### HTML :

```
<label for="start-date">Start Date</label>
<input name="start-date" id="start-date" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "useNewStyle":true,"overrideDateFormat":"%-m/%-d/%Y"}'/>
<label for="end-date">End Date</label>
<input name="end-date" id="end-date" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "useNewStyle":true,"overrideDateFormat":"%m/%-d/%Y"}'/>
```

#### Javascript

```
$('#end-date').bind('datebox', function(e, p) {
    if ( p.method === 'set' && $('#start-date').val().length > 0) {
         e.stopImmediatePropagation();
         var startDate = new Date($('#start-date').val());
         var endDate = new Date($('#end-date').val());

         if (startDate > endDate)
         {
             $('#end-date').val('');
         }  
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not need to empty field if it is not correct, I need to disable the dates in calendar.

Comment: If this is it please accept this answer. Also if you need more help regarding this topic feel free to mail me.

Comment: @user2632980: please accept this answer if it was useful to you.