# How to disable the already selected date for next date box in J.T.Sage DateBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-mobile, datebox

I my application i use jt.sage DateBox. I want to disable the already selected datepicker for next date box fields for **example my Date1 is like 13.08.14 my other date box fields need to select after 13.08.14 (NOTE : depends on previous date fields)**.

Here is the [FIDDLE FOR](http://jsfiddle.net/ktbcP/529/) date box demo.

It has lot of options like **prevent tomorrow and yesterday day but not include after select the current date**

```
        <label for="mydate">Date 1</label>
        <input  id="date1" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}' onclick="filterDate(this.id);"/>
        <label for="mydate">Date 2</label>
        <input  id="date2" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}' onclick="filterDate(this.id);"/>
        <label for="mydate">Date 3</label>
        <input  id="date3" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}' onclick="filterDate(this.id);"/>
        <label for="mydate">Date 4</label>
        <input  id="date4" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}' onclick="filterDate(this.id);"/>
        <label for="mydate">Date 5</label>
        <input  id="date5" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}' onclick="filterDate(this.id);"/>
```

How to do this please help to solve this one.

Comment: [look this example](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak thanks but i am using this for mobile application so i need above mentioned one..

Comment: try this link it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734957/how-set-end-day-based-on-start-day-in-jquery-mobile-date-picker/18736133#18736133

Comment: @Sheetal thanks but i need for mode:datebox

Comment: Works for mode datebox also : http://jsfiddle.net/QTuma/51/

Comment: @Sheetal thanks i dont wnat to select already selected date..in your fiddle i am able to select previously selected date..

Comment: You can disable a datebox like this: $("#date1").datebox("disable"); To re-enable it: $("#date1").datebox("enable");

Comment: @ezanker thanks for your reply..not disable the date box..need to disable the previously selected dates..(NOTE: when date fields are dynamically generated).

Comment: You can prevent earlier dates like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yDyqs/12/. For dynamically generated, assign a common class and use event delegation.

Comment: @ezanker thanks for your reply...i did what you mention...there is no way to disable dates in datpicker?...

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you : http://jsfiddle.net/QTuma/52/

```
Just change in the logic for difference calculation:

Start Date
// Get the difference
          var diff = parseInt((((startDate.getTime() - todaysDate.getTime()) / lengthOfDay)+2)*-1,10); 

And End Date

 // Get the difference
          var diff = parseInt((((endDate.getTime() - todaysDate.getTime()) / lengthOfDay)),10); 

This will work for the statement 'example my start date is like 13.08.14 my end date box fields need to select after 13.08.14 .'
```

Comment: thanks for your effort +1 and  my time format is like 13.08.2014 and  also i generate the date fields dynamically(i dont how many date field present any idea about this)

Comment: Format can be set using these data-options  <input name="end-date" id="end-date" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true,"overrideDateFormat":"%d/%-m/%Y", "overrideDateFieldOrder": ["d", "m", "y"]}'/>

Answer (score -1):

I have updated your code based on below reference,

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ktbcP/528/
```

This should solve your issue,

```
http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/doc/6-2-link/
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: thanks i will go through..but i am using older version of datebox